Are these two probability formulas equal?
For the Coupon Collector Problem, Wikipedia shows how to calculate the distribution using Martingales:
$$Pr(N=k) = \frac{e^{\large-kc}}{k!} e^{\large-e^{\Large-c}}.$$
In a previous question (Deriving the formulas for the Coupon Collector Problem), I found this formula to be:
$$ P(T \leq k) = \frac{1}{n^k} \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} (n-i)^k. $$
I am trying to understand if they are equal. Can someone please help me with this?

They are not equal. The WP article is poorly written but the mention that their formula holds in the limit $n\to\infty,.$
